# npm root: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm

What does `npm root` return?

I know here is how `npm` finds the `node_modules` directory:

> Look for the module in the ./node_modules directory. If it is not there, recursively search in the parent directories’ ./node_modules until either the module is found or the root of the file system is reached.

Will `npm root` returns the same thing?

I have a `node_modules` directory up in a higher place, say `/path/to/mynpmroot`, but when doing `npm root` at a much lower place, say `/path/to/mynpmroot/then/very/deep/here`, the `npm root` gives me the path of `/path/to/mynpmroot/then/very/deep/node_modules`.

Is it normal? Because when I do `ls /path/to/mynpmroot/then/very/deep/node_modules`, I'll get:

```
ls: /path/to/mynpmroot/then/very/deep/node_modules: No such file or directory
```

This is annoying to me. but do I need to care? 
(as running node scripts within `/path/to/mynpmroot/then/very/deep/here` are just fine).

How could it happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm root` uses the folder returned by `npm prefix`, which searches for the closest `package.json` file.

Normally, you'll have a `package.json` file in `/myproject/package.json`; running `npm root` from `/myproject/src/controllers` should return `/myproject/node_modules`. If for some reason you have a `package.json` file *closer* (in your controllers folder... for some reason), that would explain the behavior.

This is using `npm` v6.0+; if you are seeing different behavior, make sure to mention what version you are using (`npm -v`).

Also note that if you are running `npm prefix` from a folder in a project *without any package.json file at all*, it will return just the current folder. That would also explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: FTA, I had a `package-lock.json` file in one of my tried cases (without a `package.json` file). I.e., it'll not only searches for the closest `package.json` file, but `package-lock.json` as well.